# Unable to draw in processing language when I integrated it with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, processing, data-visualization

My setup method looks like below, I want to read one location file(City names with x and y co-ordinates) and then I am creating one hash-map of all cities so that I can draw(Will make points) them all on canvas

```java
public void setup(){
    background(0);

    PFont title = createFont("Georgia", 16);
    textFont(title);
    text("This is a visualization of A* algorithm", 240, 20);

    stroke(255);
    line(0,25,800,25);

    selectInput("Select a file for Locations:", "locFileSelected");


}
```

locFileSelected method(locFilePath is a global variable used):

```java
public void locFileSelected(File locFile) {
    locFilePath = locFile.toString();
    this.readLocFileAndDraw();
}
```

Now control is transferred to readLocFileAndDraw (Each line in file has space separated 3 words, 1st is city name followed by x and y co-ordinates:

```java
private  void readLocFileAndDraw() {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(locFilePath))) {
        for (String line : (Iterable<String>) lines::iterator){
            // Last line in file is END, skip it
            if(!line.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
                List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
                String[] arr= line.split(" ");

                // adding coordinates into the list
                list.add(Double.valueOf(arr[1]));
                list.add(Double.valueOf(arr[2]));
                // adding the list into the map with key as city name
                locationsMap.put(arr[0], list);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }


    // Draw cities on map
    // Draw graph of all cities
    int w=1, h=1;

    Set<Entry<String, List<Double>>> locationKeyEntries = locationsMap.entrySet();
    for(Entry<String, List<Double>> currEntry: locationKeyEntries) {
        String currCity = currEntry.getKey();

        List<Double> currLocationList = currEntry.getValue();

        int x = currLocationList.get(0).intValue();
        int y = currLocationList.get(1).intValue();

        stroke(255);
        ellipse(x, y, w, h);
        if(x>755)
            x = x-(8*currCity.length());
        if(y>755)
            y=y-(8*currCity.length());
        text(currCity, x,y);

    }
    return;

}
```

I tried to debug it, control is going to ellipse method but nothing is getting drew. Any idea? As far as I understand, I am missing passing reference of PApplet but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: I tried to create one more class and passed this reference in constructor. By this new class's object, I tried to call readLocFileAndDraw(). It didn't work either.
I referred topic "Processing in Eclipse with Multiple Classes" on https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

Like you've mentioned, you really need to [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). Verifying that you're calling the `ellipse()` function is a great first step, but now you should be asking yourself more questions:

- What is the value of `x`, `y,` `w`, and `h` being passed into the `ellipse()` function?
- What is the value of `currEntry` in the `for` loop? What is the value of `line` when you're reading it in?
- What are the fill, stroke, and background colors when you're drawing?

Note that I'm not asking you to tell me the answer to these questions. I'm pointing out these questions because they're what you should be asking yourself when you debug your program.

If you still can't figure it out, I really recommend [breaking your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and approaching each of those steps one at a time. For example, can you just show a single circle at a hard-coded point? Then work your way up from there. Can you read a single point in from a file and draw that to the screen? Then read two points. Work your way forward in small incremental steps, and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I will do it and post MCVE if needed. I checked x, y, w, h. They are populating properly and currEntry is for each city whose key is city name and value is location in terms of x and y coordinates. Line corrsponds to each line of input file so that I can put each city with it's location in map iteratively. May be I am messing with background colors. I will check more on it.

Comment: I am still having trouble sir, I will share a small example in new post. Please share your verdict there, Thanks. Also, later on, if you suggest then I will delete this question. @Kevin Workman

Comment: @JeetendraAhuja I don't think you should delete this question. It's a process of debugging, so this might be useful to somebody in the future. But really it's up to you.

Comment: Will not do so :) Posting another question now.